# Why is scanf always returning 1?

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>    

int main() {
    int days = scanf("%d", &days);
    printf("%d", days);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is 1 no matter what.

```
7
1
```

I've used scanf plenty of times and have never encountered this. What's the deal here?

Comment: You just clobbered the value of `days` with a **return code** from `scanf` function.

Comment: What about the documentation of `scanf` is not clear?

Comment: Time to read the man page, surely?

Answer (score 3):

This is correct, because, `scanf()` returns number of successfully matched and converted elements. Considering proper input in your case, every time your input passes the conversion, so you get to see the value 1.

Point to note, `scanf()` **does not return** the scanned value itself, it stores the value in the passed argument.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.4

> [...] the `scanf` function returns the
>   number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in
>   the event of an early matching failure.

Comment: @user3643077: you must be doing it differently elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of scanf is to indicate if it successfully read an integer.

This will do what you're expecting

```
#include <stdio.h>    

int main() {
    int days = 0;
    scanf("%d", &days);
    printf("%d", days);
    return  0;
}
```

Comment: This does not mean you should ignore it.

Comment: Thanks. char limit

Comment: @WeatherVane Agreed, but this is an extremely simple program. I am just trying to demonstrate the behaviour OP was asking about.